# System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the path 'Google.Apis.Auth' is denied with Gmail Api

Tags: asp.net

I have implemented Gmail Api for email management..but on my local IIS , it's giving below error

System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the path 'Google.Apis.Auth' is denied.

I have given permission to "EveryOne" on the Project Folder and also on the "~\AppData\Roaming\Google.Apis.Auth" as  i have read somewhere that Gmail Api access this folder for token/details..

Following code i am using :

UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("/") + "client_secrets_desktop.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly },
                    "user", CancellationToken.None);
            }

```
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Gmail Test",
        });





        try
        {
            ListLabelsResponse response = service.Users.Labels.List("me").Execute();
            //foreach (Label label in response.Labels.OrderBy(p => p.Name))
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(label.Id + " - " + label.Name);
            //}
        }
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem and solved it adding the dataStore parameter to

```
GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()
```

the call that generates the credentials. That is adding FileDataStore(storage)

```
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, 
            Scopes,
            createdByUser, 
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(storage)).Result;
```

where 'storage' is a local folder (ex. /App_Data/folder) where ASP.NET user should have read/write permissions.